# Parallel-For loop giving different sum results than single for loop. What am I missing?

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, parallel.for

We have an obscure bug in one of our programs. I've narrowed at least part of it down to this parallel-for loop.

i is an int[], for testing purposes, filled with ints 0 - 99999.
runningTotal is a long.
lockObject is a new Object();

The Parallel-For loop always seems to return the total 704,982,704 when complete; the single-threaded loop returns 4,999,950,000.

So obviously a threading issue, but I just don't see the mistake. Is the Parallel-For loop implemented properly?

Relevant code below:

```
//i int[] test ---------------------------------------------
object lockObject = new object();
int[] i = new int[100000];
for (int x = 0; x < i.Length; x++)
{
    i[x] = x;
}
long runningTotal = 0;

Parallel.For(0, i.Length,
() => 0,
(x, loopState, subtotal) =>
{
    subtotal += i[x];
    return subtotal;
},
(s) =>
{
    lock (lockObject)
    {
        runningTotal += s;
    }
}
);
runningTotal = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < i.Length; x++)
{
    runningTotal += i[x];
}
```

Comment: This is really peculiar. It overflows intermittently in my tests when `localinit` returns a 0 (`Int32`), but works reliably if `localinit` is `Int64` (`Parallel.For(0, i.Length, () => 0L ...`)

Comment: I tried what you suggested and yeah, it's working perfectly now and seems to have resolved our issue. Thanks! If you can put that into a "Response", I'll mark is as the answer.

Comment: It's not really an answer I can be happy with until I know exactly why the issue is occurring. I'll do some digging and report back once I've got a comprehensive explanation.

Comment: *I think* I know what it is. The number of parallel workers

Comment: Maybe the init has to be marked as long because even though it's in the Parallel-Loop, there could possibly only be 1 task allocated, and thus would cause things to overflow. The degree of parallelism is automatically managed by the underlying components of the system. Is that kind of what you're leaning towards?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right.

Comment: Upvoted for giving precise code that illustrated the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is that local state is declared as `int` and sometimes overflows.

This happens intermittently and has to do with the number of worker threads that `Parallel.For` throws at the task at hand. You can get the overflow to happen reliably if you limit `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to 1.

The fix is to declare local state as `long`:

```
Parallel.For(0, i.Length, () => 0L, ...)
```

... then the overflow never occurs. Other than that there is nothing wrong with your logic.

Comment: Marked as answer since we figured it out. Thanks for your help and insight!

Comment: @FreeCoder24, this was fun. Thanks for creating a concise repro of the problem.